# SharePoint Apps - Can we have multiple Client Webpart in a sharePoint app?

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-addin

Can we have multiple Client Webpart in a sharePoint app? If so, do we need to do any configurations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have many app parts. Here is a guide to get you started: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/apps/fp179921.aspx